# Proper use of a functor in std::for_each and std::transform

Tags: c++, c++11, functor

This may be a naive question but here it goes anyway :

Suppose I have a class like this :

```
class func {
    public:
        int operator()(int it) const { return it + 21; }
};
```

As it's clear, a functor is defined in the above class, and if I do this :

```
func obj;
int capture = obj(9);
cout << capture << endl;
```

The result will be 30, as is obvious. But let's suppose I use STL's `std::transform` to transform one container using the values of another container according to the functor defined above:

```
vector<int> v, vi;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
vi.resize(v.size());
```

I follow the below syntax, where I'm invoking the functor directly using the class-name, and also, no argument is passed to the functor (which it requires according to the definition) :

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), vi.begin(), func());
```

This works perfectly. Why does this happen? Despite not using an instance of `func` and also without passing an argument (which is the element of the first container apparently), why does this work?

Also, if I use an instance of `func`, with an argument as I did above, it causes a compilation error.

```
 func instance;
 std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), vi.begin(), instance());
```

How to use a functor properly in `std::transform/std::for_each`? Why is there a difference in the way the functor method is invoked?

Also, from [this answer on functors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/356993/4806357), we have the following piece of code :

```
// this is a functor
struct add_x {
  add_x(int x) : x(x) {}
  int operator()(int y) const { return x + y; }

  private:
    int x;
};

std::vector<int> in; // assume this contains a bunch of values)
std::vector<int> out(in.size());
// Pass a functor to std::transform, which calls the functor on every element 
// in the input sequence, and stores the result to the output sequence
std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), out.begin(), add_x(1));
```

The answer states that `add_x(1)` acts a functor here (and not an instance), how is it an instance in the above example I gave?

Comment: This is an instance: `lambda_function()`.

Comment: If its an instance, how is it working as a functor, without an argument ? Shouldn't it throw a compilation-error ?

Comment: Why are you calling things "lambda_function" and "capture" when your code has nothing to do with lambda functions and captures?

Comment: The answer you linked seems to use the term "functor" for both functor classes and their instances, which can be a bit confusing for a beginner. (Non-beginners can often tell from the context whether it refers to a class or an instance of a class.) `add_x(1)` is a functor object which is an instance of the `add_x` functor class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), vi.begin(), lambda_function());
//                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That isn't invoking `lambda_function::operator()`, it is just creating a temporary instance of `lambda_function`. Inside `std::transform`, this object will have its `operator()` called iteratively with the contents of `v` as arguments.

It's more obvious what is happening if you use C++11's braced initialization:

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), vi.begin(), lambda_function{});
```

Or perhaps if you consider this:

```
lambda_function()(0);
//             ^^    creates instance
//               ^^^ calls operator()
```

---

Regarding your second example:

```
std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), out.begin(), add_x(1));
//                                                ^^^^^^^^
```

This again creates a temporary instance of `add_x`, but instead of calling the default constructor, it calls the `add_x(int x);` constructor. This initialises some state in the function object so that when `operator()` is called inside `std::transform`, it adds the given number.

Comment: If it isn't invoking the functor, how is it taking every element and adding 21 to it ?

Comment: The function object is being invoked inside the algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

In this,

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), vi.begin(), lambda_function());
```

`lambda_function()` default-creates a temporary instance of `lambda_function`.
`lambda_function` is a class, not an object.
`lambda_function()` is an object.

In

```
lambda_function instance;
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), vi.begin(), instance());
```

you're not passing the instance, you're trying to call an `operator()` with no arguments.
`instance` is an object, not a class.

To pass the instance, write

```
lambda_function instance;
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), vi.begin(), instance);
```

Comment: @Jarvis See if my comment under the question makes anything clearer.

Comment: Actually not completely, how does `add_x(1)` adds 1 to every element of the first container, whereas the definition of `add_x(int y)` adds `y` to the class-member `x` ? Also, is `add_x(1)` the constructor calling or the functor calling ?

Answer (score 3):

`std::transform(InIt first, InIt last, OutIt dest, Fn f)` in essence does this:

```
while (first != last) {
    *dest = f(*first);
    first++;
}
```

So when you call

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(). vi.begin(), lambda_function());
```

you're creating a temporary object of type `lambda_function` and passing that object to `transform`. Inside `transform`, that object gets called on each element of the input range, just like in your code `int capture = obj(9);`.

To use an object that you've already created instead of a temporary, just pass it in:

```
lambda_function instance;
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), vi.begin(), instance);
```

Note that this code does not have `()` after `instance`; that would be calling `operator()` with no arguments, and `lambda_function` does not have an `operator()` that can be called with no arguments.

Comment: @Jarvis - no, I'm not going to try to track your moving target.

Comment: Just consider a small addition I made, where it does not behave as an instance, but as the real functor, how does it work then ?

Answer (score 0):

See the difference:

```
lambda_function obj;
int capture = obj(9);
cout << capture << endl;
```

vs

```
int capture = lambda_function()(9);
cout << capture << endl;
```

and second example:

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(). vi.begin(), lambda_function());
```

vs

```
lambda_function obj;
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(). vi.begin(), obj);
```

latest example:

```
std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), out.begin(), add_x(1));
```

vs

```
add_x obj( 1 );
std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), out.begin(), obj);
```